# disable access to an url if a div is present

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, conditional-statements

I have a countdown timer plugin installed inside my wordpress website and I want to disable acces to a specific URL till the countdown timer is over.

At this moment, I know when the countdown timer is over by checking if a div has a specific class.

This is how I'm checking with jquery:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}

if ( jQuery(".hasCountdown").exists()) {
// do something
}
});
```

But then if the user disable the javascript this is not good anymore.

So I need to do this by php.

**L.E: I'm using WORDPRESS and I will have more pages with countdown timers.**
Any suggestion is welcome. 
Thanks!

Comment: I imagine one way to do this would to set a hash or session token to in the URL once the countdown is over. If the user has Javascript disabled, the session token won't be applied to the URL, and the URL will be invalid (which you can check from the PHP side.) Since it's a short countdown, you can give the user a timer to click on the URL before it becomes an invalid token.

Comment: I don't think I understand the "has a specific class" logic.  A user can remove a class from any HTML element at any time and get around the JS timer limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NEVER rely on Javascript for blocking a user from doing anything they are not allowed to do.  JS can be circumvented in so many ways by the user that any restrictions are impossible to enforce.

I would recommend you do the important check on the server side.  In this case, I would recommend the following flow:

- On page load, set a future timestamp in the session (the time at which the link should start working)
- Add a regular link to the HTML
- When the link is clicked, fire off an AJAX call to a server side script to check if the timestamp has been reached.
- If it hasn't been reached, sent a response to the client that tells the JS to stop (i.e. don't do anything).
- If it has been reached, have the server send back an 'OK' and have the client follow the URL (via `window.location`).

**In all cases**, you need to check the timestamp on the destination URL and throw up an "Access Denied" warning if the timestamp has not been reached.

Comment: I like this approach but I don't know if it's working for me because I will have more pages, for example I will have a page now which has a 3 days countdown and after this is done I will have another page with another 3 days countdown and so on... so the time at which the link should start working should be changed everytime I will add a new page ?

Comment: and also what about if the user typing directly the url in the browser address bar and not click on a link? I need to stop him also doing this...

Comment: To your second question: As I said, you need to **always** check the timestamp when you load the restricted page in the browser.  If the user enters too soon (no matter if they use the link or go there directly) you throw up a warning and don't show the real page.  In short, it doesn't matter of you implement the JS part, it will always be protected. The JS just makes it nicer for the user, so they don't see the warning if they are not allowed to go there anyways.

Comment: Can you give me a short  code example of how I can use this ?

Comment: To your first question: You can create page specific timeouts.  But if we are talking about 3 days, you probably can't use the session but should ideally create some database dependent solution.  Just create a table that holds (at least) three columns: one for the userid, one for the page to be accessed and one for the timestamp.

Comment: My PHP is a little rusty, but in pseudocode it would be: `if(now() < theTimestamp) { echo "Access Denied"; die(); }`

Comment: So, if it's about days is not really a good idea to use timestamp ?

Comment: No, you still need the timestamp, but you need to store it in a database, not the session.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a "turn javascript on" with php and then replace it with cooldown block with javascript when page is loaded.

So if user loaded your page without js, he will see "turn javascript on".

If javascript is on, this text will be replaced with cooldown block and url if needed.

Comment: I like this approach but I don't know if it's working for me because I will have more pages, for example I will have a page now which has a 3 days countdown and after this is done I will have another page with another 3 days countdown and so on... so the time at which the link should start working should be changed everytime I will add a new page ?

Comment: @Alecs in general, _In all cases, you need to check the timestamp on the destination URL and throw up an "Access Denied" warning if the timestamp has not been reached._ by Steve is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

You could have 2 timers, one javascript and another in php.
The current one in the javascript would stay the same, no changes needed.
The difference would be that when the user loads the page in php, you save a timestamp in the session. Then, in the URL you want to block, get the timestamp from the session and check if enough time has passed. If it hasn't, then you can block, redirect, or take any action you want.
The user would not have a feedback about this "other" timer, but you would make sure that either the user has javascript active or not, or even if the user tampered your html/javascript through the browser console, he wouldn't be able to access your "blocked" URL before the timer ends.
Cheers.